# PHP & Android custom sign in not working

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

Registracion part working great(not included here) , 
But when I click on Sign In Button(bLogin) it gives me this:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for name
```

This is LoginActivity.class:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final TextView tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);

        tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                // Response received from the server
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("age", age);
                                intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think error would be in php part , but I can't find exactly where it is.
And this is login.php:

```
        <?php
  $con = "Connection works fine.";

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $username, $age,$password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: What the DDL for the `user` table? Do you have a column `name` in there?

Comment: yes I have , same database works great for registration , But login gave me nothing (all of them(name,age,username) are empty). it just can't get data from database./